# Set default database for connection

Tags: teradata

Super n00b question, I know, but I can't seem to find it anywhere that's easy to find, so it would be good to document this here.

Say I connect to a Teradata system as a particular user, `NICK`, but I need to access tables owned by a different user, `BOB`.

Instead of having to qualify each table name with `BOB.` I'd like to just set my default database for the connection to `BOB` and then query the tables using their unqualified name.

In other words, instead of this:

```
-- Cartesian Join of Doom (CJD™)
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM BOB.TABLE1, BOB.TABLE2, BOB.TABLE3;
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
-- CJD™ for the lazy
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3;
```

Is there a way to do this for the life of a connection?

Comment: a quick google suggests you just need to issue `database dbname`. Similar to an alter session set current_schema in oracle

Comment: @Phil - That should be it, but when I try to run a simple `SELECT` after that I get this: `Only an ET or null statement is legal after a DDL Statement.` It looks like we need to do something immediately after the `DATABASE ...` statement.

Comment: Aha, it looks like `ET` from that error message means `END TRANSACTION`. Doing that right after the `DATABASE ...` statement makes subsequent queries work. @Phil - Wanna submit your comment as an answer, or should I do the honors?

Comment: Have done, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to issue:

```
database dbname
```

Similar to an `alter session set current_schema` in oracle.

Comment: And in some cases you may need to add an `END TRANSACTION` immediately after that before you can run other statements.